# Factory pattern with inheritance

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I am having a problem with Factory pattern when it use with Inheritance,

This is my code

```
public class Animal {
  public int numberOfLegs() { return 2 ;}
}

public class Cat extends Animal {
  public String getSound() {return "Maaaw";}
}
public class Dog extends Animal {
  public String getSound() {return "woof";}
}

public class AnimalFactory {
  public Animal getAnimal(String name){
    Animal an= null ;
    if(name=="cat"){an = new Cat();}
    else if(name=="dog"){an=new Dog();}
    return an ;
  }
}

public class FactoryDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    AnimalFactory anmF=new AnimalFactory();
    Animal anm=anmF.getAnimal("cat") ;
    System.out.println("legs : "+anm.numberOfLegs()); // working fine
    System.out.println("sound : "+anm.getSound());    // giving error
  }
}
```

When I run this, I can't go to the `getSound()` method. It giving a error.

This'll work fine if I define the `Animal` class as Abstract class,
But I want to how to deal Factory pattern such a situation like this.

Comment: It helps to know what error you get. Please include it in your question.

Comment: If you think all animals should have a sound, then the getSound() method should be part of the Animal class. It doesn't have anything to do with the factory pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you included, is nothing like a Factory anything. If you refer to the [Factory Method Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) then, what you implemented as part of your OP is an incorrect implementation. There are two "Factory" code designs, one is the Factory Method Pattern I indicated before (your code is definitely not that) and the Factory recommended in the Effective Java book, which is the design of choice for the Java JDK i.e. the `valueOf` or `create*` methods.

Comment: A bit late to the party... @SkyWalker why do you think it is not nothing like Factory anything? Isn't this exactly Factory Method Pattern if AnimalFactory would implement a AnimalFactory interface?

Answer (score 8):

You need to add an abstract method for getSound

```
public abstract class Animal {
    public int numberOfLegs() { return 2 ;}
    public abstract String getSound();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Yes it solved the issue, but i want to know is there any way to do this without define Animal class as Abstract ?

Comment: You would need to provide a default implementation of `getSound()`.

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to:

```
public abstract class Animal {
    public int numberOfLegs() { 
        return 2;
    }

    public abstract String getSound();
}


public class Cat extends Animal {
    public String getSound() {
        return "Maaaw";
    }
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
    public String getSound() {
        return "woof";
    }
}

public class AnimalFactory {
    public Animal getAnimal(String name) {

        Animal an = null;
        if ("cat".equals(name)) {
            an = new Cat();
        } else if ("dog".equals(name)) {
            an = new Dog();
        } 
        return an;
     }
}
```

You shall add abstract method, and use *equals* in your factory method instead of using *==* on Objects.

Comment: Thanks, Yes it solved the issue, but i want to know is there any way to do this without define Animal class as Abstract ?

Comment: Of course. Just add an implementation for getSound in animal and remove the abstract keyword.

Comment: Great explanation , but this is an example of Simple Factory pattern which is usually not considered as an design pattern. It would be great to use Factory method design pattern when it comes to java inheritance as it would safeguard us to avoid any existing code change when new classes will be added in the hierarchy.